# MissingMethodException when using Unquote asserts

Tags: f#, nunit, missingmethodexception, f#-unquote

I'm trying to use [unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/) with NUnit as the test runner. The test case is taken from [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/wiki/GettingStarted) and works as expected when run outside of NUnit:

```
namespace FsTest.Tests

open NUnit.Framework
open Swensen.Unquote

[<TestFixture>]
module Example =

    [<Test>]
    let foo() = 
        test <@ (1+2)/3 = 1 @>
```

Under NUnit I get this exception:

> FsTest.Tests.Example.foo: System.MissingMethodException : Method not
>   found:
>   'System.Tuple`2<Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1,Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr>
>   Internal.reduceFullyAndGetLast(Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr)'.

I'd like to know if there's anything wrong with the code above and how I could make it work. Unquote's `raise` fail for me in the same way if that helps.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "run outside of NUnit" and "Under NUnit"? This issue looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7828852/236255 except with the xUnit.net GUI test runner, where the OP learned he was referencing the wrong version of FSharp.Core.dll

Comment: *"run outside of NUnit"* means using F# Interactive or a command line application from the same solution; *"Under NUnit"* means using a stock NUnit 2.6.2 GUI runner downloaded as a zip file. FScharp.Core.dll is referenced from the test assembly: `<Reference Include="FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">`. The whole thing is VS 2012 targeting .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the description of your problem, I suspect you need to configure your NUnit project with an `FSharp.Core` binding redirect from version 4.0.0.0 to version 4.3.0.0 since the latest version of Unquote is built for .NET 4.0 and your test project targets .NET 4.5.

See [this](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/issues/detail?id=78) Unquote issue for details. I believe your configuration would look something like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
          name="FSharp.Core"
          publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect
          oldVersion="2.0.0.0"
          newVersion="4.3.0.0"/>
        <bindingRedirect
          oldVersion="4.0.0.0"
          newVersion="4.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure exactly where you would need to put this for an NUnit project, but maybe in the config file specified through the [Project Editor](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=projectEditor&r=2.2)?

Unfortunately, I don't have VS2012 installed and so I am somewhat crippled in my ability to really diagnose this issue for you.

Comment: Great, that helped, thanks. For those who interested, NUnit uses `<TestAssemblyName>.dll.config` to configure test DLLs, so that's where you put these settings.